# How to set systemProperty from gradle task in Kotlin dsl?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

Given that systemProperty is set for the "run" task in gradle.build script using groovy syntax as:

```
run { 
    systemProperty "some.property.key", "property value" 
}
```

how to do the same in Kotlin dsl?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:properties

Answer (score 1):

not sure this is the best approach - but - here is what i got working :

```
application {
    mainClassName = "..."
    run {
        val defaultJvmArgs = applicationDefaultJvmArgs.toMutableList()
        defaultJvmArgs.add("-Dkey=value")
        setApplicationDefaultJvmArgs(defaultJvmArgs)
    }
}
```